# OrderClose By Time

Tags: mql4

```
if( OrderMagicNumber()==2 )
      {         
          if( TimeCurrent() - OrderOpenTime() > 1800 &&   Bid - OrderOpenPrice() > 5*_Point  )
          {
              OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Bid,3,Yellow);
          }    
          if( Bid - OrderOpenPrice()  > 50*_Point ){
              RevSF = true ;
          }     
          if(     RevSF == true  )
          { 
             if(    Bid -OrderOpenPrice() < 10*_Point &&  Bid -OrderOpenPrice() > 8*_Point )
             {
                 OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Bid,3,Yellow);
                 RevSF = false ;
             }
         }    
     }
```

I have some code to close buy orders, it depends on time elapsed since order opening and also depends on current market price (Bid must be higher than the order open price). However when I attached it to chart in terminal it opened orders in the real market, but it's closing it after time elapsed without taking the current market price in to consideration.

However this is not happening in testing

This is what happen in testing:
[image: this is what happen in testing]

Comment: Okay... what is your code? (edit your post to include the code)

Comment: man thnx for respoding

Comment: in real market the position was closed automatically  without my interfere after 30 min

Comment: but not like what testing image show , in testing image it was closed after 50 min i think when position was lower than Bid by 5 point as the second part of the condition stat in real market second part of the condition is ignored i dont know why its all about the first condition in the code . account history showed my that i lost 10 dollar because pos opend at 6:2 and closed at 6;32

Comment: print logs to see what happened in tester and why EA decided to close the deal. 1800 in your code is time in seconds. In the real market slippage may happen, that's why log the current price before OrderClose() is called.